# Majority layer in Keras?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

Is there any kind of majority layer in Keras? That the input would be dome 1D vector, and the output is a single number which is the value that has the most occurrences kn the input vector?

My use case is - I'm building an ensemble of neural networks, but let's say that I want to have a single network. So I'm building a new network, with the previous models as inputs. I want to add a dingle output layer that simply runs a majority vote. Is it possible with Keras?

Answer (score 0):

Note, that such a layer would not make much sense with float activations, since probability of two floats being exactly the same is 0. Consequently this only makes sense if your inputs are categorical. And for categorical layer you usually one-hot encode the result, thus imagine having N networks with one hot encoding of K possible values, thus N x K tensor

```
Net 1:  0 0 1 0 0 0 
Net 2:  1 0 0 0 0 0 
Net 3:  0 0 1 0 0 0
```

Now all we have to do is to sum over N

```
        1 0 2 0 0 0
```

and take an argmax to find what you want. So you just compose 2 standard operations from every NN library - summation, and argmaxing. Note, that this solution actually works also if your inputs are floats, you "sum" the votes, and take an argmax.